# Gitlab pull push not working

Tags: ruby, git, gitlab

`OVERVIEW`

I am using Gitlab server locally in ubuntu 13.10 and I got following output in these command

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

System information
System:     Ubuntu 13.10
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.0.0p247
Gem Version:    2.0.3
Bundler Version:1.5.3
Rake Version:   10.1.0

GitLab information
Version:    6.0.2
Revision:   10b0b8f
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        http://192.168.0.104
HTTP Clone URL: http://192.168.0.104/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@192.168.0.104:some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.7.0
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
xxx@xxx:/home/git/gitlab$ cd /home/git/
```

Now I sucessfully logged into the server with admin@local.host and create member and project. Then when I clone to the new project called testgitlab 
 by `git clone http://192.168.0.104/sss/testgitlab.git`
I could clone the project.

```
PROBLEM
```

1. When I try to commit the project I could do that. After commiting the project when I try to pull the Project `git pull origin master` then following error occurs:

```
:~/Desktop/testgitlab$ git pull origin master
Username for 'http://192.168.0.104': sss
Password for 'http://sss@192.168.0.104': 
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
Unexpected end of command stream
```

2. After I get unsucessful in pulling the project I tried to push the project:

```
    ~/Desktop/testgitlab$ git push origin master
Username for 'http://192.168.0.104': sss
Password for 'http://sss@192.168.0.104': 
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 220 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find json-1.7.7 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `setup'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To http://192.168.0.104/username/testgitlab.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://192.168.0.104/sss/testgitlab.git'
```

When checking the gitlab status

```
    sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.0 ? ... OK (1.7.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
post-receive hooks in repos are links: ... 
Administrator / sesh ... repository is empty
sss / TestGitlab ... repository is empty

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
Projects have satellites? ... 
Administrator / sesh ... can't create, repository is empty
sss / TestGitlab ... can't create, repository is empty
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.8.3)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

I cannot figure out what I am missing ....
Help me out .
Thank you in advace !!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem related to the issue 3384 that @Jonathan is referring to.

I solved it allowing the `git` user to login (modifying the `/etc/passwd` to set the shell to bash for the git user).
See my answer here: [GitLab 7-0 stable not able to push or clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656063/gitlab-7-0-stable-not-able-to-push-or-clone/27022284#27022284)

Answer (score 0):

An issue on github indicates, that it might have something to do with the unicorn/nginx/gitlab-shell configuration. Make sure to double check all the configs:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3384