# GitLab 7-0 stable not able to push or clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, vpn, gitlab

**Hi, I tried various links and configuration setting to resolve my issue. but I’m not able to do so. 
If you still feel the question is copy or not useful I'm requesting you to please and a comment and I will delete the question without bother anyone.**

I did **gitlab 7-0 stable** setup in a fresh ubuntu 12.04 64 bit machine in a local network.
my sever domain name is 192.168.1.1(**some static IP within my LAN**).

After this I can able to login both admin and user. I can create **project ,group all basic work through web UI.**

But I'm **not able to clone or pushing code to the server using ssh** from some other system in my LAN.

the result for **sudo ./bin/check** is

```
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files: 
    /home/git/repositories/: OK
    /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Test redis-cli executable: redis-cli 2.2.12
Send ping to redis server: PONG
```

and all my system status are GREEN.

suspecting that it might be a problem of **gitlab.yml , nginx,unicorn** configuration.

can anyone please help me?

Update:
my **config/gitlab.yml**

```
  production: &base
  ## GitLab settings
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings (note: host is the FQDN, do not include http://)
    host: 192.168.1.37
    port: 80
    https: false
  email_from: example@example.com
    default_projects_limit: 10
    ## Default project features settings
    default_projects_features:
      issues: true
      merge_requests: true
      wiki: true
      snippets: false
      visibility_level: "private"  # can be "private" | "internal" | "public"
      issues_tracker:
   ## Gravatar
  gravatar:
    enabled: true                 # Use user avatar image from Gravatar.com (default: true)
   ldap:
    enabled: false
    host: '_your_ldap_server'
    port: 636
    uid: 'sAMAccountName'
    method: 'ssl' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
    bind_dn: '_the_full_dn_of_the_user_you_will_bind_with'
    password: '_the_password_of_the_bind_user'
    allow_username_or_email_login: true
satellites:
    # Relative paths are relative to Rails.root (default: tmp/repo_satellites/)
    path: /home/git/gitlab-satellites/
  ## Backup settings
  backup:
    path: "tmp/backups"   # Relative paths are relative to Rails.root (default: tmp/backups/)
    # keep_time: 604800   # default: 0 (forever) (in seconds)
  ## GitLab Shell settings
  gitlab_shell:
    path: /home/git/gitlab-shell/
    # REPOS_PATH MUST NOT BE A SYMLINK!!!
    repos_path: /home/git/repositories/
    hooks_path: /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/

    # Git over HTTP
    upload_pack: true
    receive_pack: true
    ssh_port: 22
git:
    bin_path: /usr/local/bin/git
    max_size: 5242880 # 5.megabytes
    # Git timeout to read a commit, in seconds
    timeout: 10
extra:
development:
  <<: *base

test:
  <<: *base
  gravatar:
    enabled: true
  gitlab:
    host: localhost
```

**And /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml**

---

```
user: git
gitlab_url: http://192.168.1.37
http_settings:
  self_signed_cert: false
repos_path: /home/git/repositories/
auth_file: /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
redis:
  bin: /usr/bin/redis-cli
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
  namespace: resque:gitlab
log_level: INFO
audit_usernames: false
~
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

When following the installation instructions, one create a `git` user with the `nologin` option. But on my Linux box (openSUSE) this blocks pull and push via SSH.

I edited the file `/etc/passwd` looking for the line starting with `git` and I replaced the end of the line with `/bin/bash` (was before `/bin/false`).

No need to restart anything. You should be able to pull and push.